# Brew MongoDB autoload mongod on login - run mongo as a service

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

I am confused.

`brew services list` is showing me that `mongod` is being loaded at login

```
mongodb    started        - /Users/myuser/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist
```

but, when I do `mongo` I get `Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:61 Connection refused`

How do I make `mongod` to `start as a service`? The content of the `.plist` file can be viewed here: http://pastebin.com/itxUtZ8M

Any suggestions much appreciated. P.S. I am running on OS X Maverick (OS X 10.9.2)

Comment: Can you see it running when you execute `ps aux | grep mongo`?

Comment: @GergoErdosi no, nothing there until I do `mongod` manually

Comment: No, that's just the grep command you executed. There should be two lines in the output. Run `brew services restart mongodb`.

Comment: @GergoErdosi nothing after `brew services restart mongodb`

Comment: So if you start `mongod` manually, then it works? Can you add the content of `/Users/myuser/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist` to your question?

Comment: When I start mongod manually I can connect to mongo

Comment: @GergoErdosi the content of the plist file can be found here: http://pastebin.com/itxUtZ8M

Comment: It looks good. What happens when you stop the service (`brew services stop mongodb`) and start it using the command `/usr/local/opt/mongodb/bin/mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf`?

Comment: @GergoErdosi - `FileNotOpen Failed to open "/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log"` - wrong path to the config file?

Comment: @GergoErdosi after chaning the ownerwhich of the login file to myself the mongod started

Comment: Ok, that will be the problem then. Path is correct. Can you run `ls -l /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log`?

Comment: @GergoErdosi does this mean the brew services will works correctly now?

Comment: @GergoErdosi got it working now! Many thanks for your time. Any suggestions of how to find this kind of issue quickly?

Comment: Good to hear that! It usually helps if you run commands manually. Service scripts (start / stop) often hide errors that are otherwise displayed when the command is executed in the terminal.

Comment: You're welcome! Added an answer in case somebody finds this question later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting `mongod` manually with the command `/usr/local/opt/mongodb/bin/mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf` showed that something was wrong with the log file:

```
FileNotOpen Failed to open "/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log"
```

As it turned out, the owner of the file was wrong. Changing it to `myuser` solved the problem. See comments below the question for details.